# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:The local variable num1 may not have been initialized

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Please enter a telephone number expressed as letters and separated with a hyphen.");
phone=console.next();
phone.toLowerCase();
letter1=phone.charAt(0);
```

This is how i use letter1 which is a char.

```
if (letter1=='a'||letter1=='b'||letter1=='c')
{num1=2;}
if (letter1=='f'||letter1=='e'||letter1=='d')
{num1=3;}
if (letter1=='g'||letter1=='h'||letter1=='i')
{num1=4;}
if (letter1=='j'||letter1=='k'||letter1=='l')
{num1=5;}
if (letter1=='m'||letter1=='n'||letter1=='o')
{num1=6;}
if (letter1=='p'||letter1=='q'||letter1=='r'||letter1=='s')
{num1=7;}
if (letter1=='t'||letter1=='u'||letter1=='v')
{num1=8;}
if (letter1=='w'||letter1=='x'||letter1=='y'||letter1=='z')
{num1=9;}
System.out.println(num1);
```

The program immediately says the num1 may not initialized without asking the question which initializes letter1. So this leads me to believe the problem is here and I probably made a syntax error or some other mistake.

Comment: `phone.toLowerCase();` will not work you need to reassign the result to `phone` as Strings are immutable.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know you only asked for letters, and it doesn't know if the user really did enter a letter and if they didn't `num1` wont be initialised to anything.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's possible to pass through **none** of the `if` cases.

You need to either define it to a default value before any of the `if` cases, or have the last one implement `if(...) {...} else {...}`, and place a default value into the `else`.

The first method is much more recommended than the second.

Also, you aren't correctly changing string to lowercase.

```
phone = console.next();
phone = phone.toLowerCase();
```

Otherwise, you're converting to lowercase, but not saving the result, and it's lost.

Answer (score 0):

There is an execution path in which you did not initialize `num1`, specifically, if `letter1` is not a lowercase letter.

Initialize `num1` to something, so it has a value in all execution paths, perhaps something invalid.

```
int num1 = -1;
```

You may even choose to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or print an error message if you make it through all your cases and `num1` is still `-1`.